# Join two Tables based on id order by time

Tags: mysql, join

I need to combine two tables and order by the two tables date..

Medicine

```
| Id | Patientid | Name | Quantity |  medicine name | Takingtype | Epoch     |
===============================================================================
|  1 |       12  | raja | 20       | Ampicillin     |    1-1-1   | 1420446675|
```

Surgical

```
| Id | Patientid | Name | medicine name | Quantity | Epoch      |
=======================================================================
|  1 |       12  | raja | Mucinex oral  | 10       | 1420446675 |
```

Can any one help me?
The Result should be like  this,

```
|s.no| Date     | Name | Quantity  |  medicine name | Takingtype |
=================================================================
|  1 | 1-5-2015 | raja |  20       | Ampicillin     |    1-1-1   |
|  2 | 1-5-2015 | raja |  10       |Mucinex oral    |            |
```

Please help me join the tables like the result showed above. I'm looking for a mysql query..

(I have changed the epoch time in to date in php..)

Comment: Join on which column?

Comment: Where does date comes from 1-5-2015? and where's the date field in your table?

Comment: @Jens you overwrote his new change with your edit.

Comment: @almasshaikh I think the date is from the epoch, which I think is a unixtime.

Comment: Did you forget about Takingtype  in second table? Or how you get it for result table? Also where did you get s.no?

Comment: Actually output looks more like UNION, then JOIN

Comment: Why do you have two tables? Fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for ***[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)*** in MySQL?

```
SELECT name, quantity, medicine, Takingtype FROM Medicine
UNION ALL
SELECT name, quantity, medicine, NULL FROM Surgical
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, then what you want is not a join, it's a union.

```sql
select * from (
    select Name, Quantity, MedicineName, Epoch, Takingtype From Medicine
        union all 
    select Name, Quantity, MedicineName, Epoch, NULL From Surgical
) x order by epoch;
```

I also assume that you want s.no to be a column that contains row ordinals. To my best knowledge you cannot really achieve that in MySQL without a temporary table (experts might correct me here).

Finally, if your datetime is indeed a time from the epoch, you need to use a [FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) builtin, something along the lines of

```sql
select * from (
    select FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(Epoch) AS Date, Name, Quantity, MedicineName, Epoch, Takingtype From Medicine 
        union all 
    select FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(Epoch) AS Date, Name, Quantity, MedicineName, Epoch, NULL From Surgical
) x order by epoch;
```